# Why is login with key authentication into gitlab behind a nat not working

Tags: gitlab

I want to use gitlab behind a router doing key authentication. For some reason it does not.
It exits already with the command git clone

```
> git clone https://git.example.org/me/project.git c:\Users\me\Documents\Workspace\project --progress
Cloning into 'c:\Users\me\Documents\Workspace\project'....
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.example.org/me/project.git/'.
```

i currently have ports 80 and 443 open, what other ports do i not need to open?
Is there a setting in gitlab that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a NAT issue. There's no ports you have to open. You're able to communicate with the remote web server just fine.

You don't try key authentication; you attempt HTTP Basic authentication. Read the error message.

Normally key authentication implies ssh. Then you don't use https://..., but user@hostname:...

Comment: What settings are needed to enable key authentication? if I access the local IP it is working smoth

Comment: You include no information about your setup, so I have no idea.